# React Native: custom header not set to header navigation

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation

I created top navigator in my android react native project :

```
const topSurvayorsNavigator = createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
    ActiveSurveyor: {
        screen: MomayezanScreen,
        params: { status: 1 },
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarLabel: <Text style={{ fontSize: 12, fontFamily: 'IranianSans' }}>ممیزان فعال</Text>,
            tabBarIcon: (tabInfo => {
                return (
                    <Icon name="stars" size={15} color={tabInfo.tintColor} />
                );
            })
        },
    },
    DeActiveSurveyor: {
        screen: MomayezanScreen,
        params: { status: 0 },
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarLabel: <Text style={{ fontSize: 12, fontFamily: 'IranianSans' }}>ممیزان غیرفعال</Text>,
            tabBarIcon: (tabInfo => {
                return (
                    <Icon name="md-stars" size={15} color={tabInfo.tintColor} />
                );
            })
        },

    }
}, {
    swipeEnabled: true,
    tabBarOptions: {
        labelStyle: {
            fontSize: 12
        },
        activeTintColor: Colors.darkGray
    }
});
```

After that i added **topSurvayorsNavigator** to main stack navigator :

```
const AuditMomayezanNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    Dashboard: DashboardScreen,
    ListSurveyor: {
        screen: topSurvayorsNavigator,
    },
    Detail: SurveyorDetailsScreen,
}, {
    defaultNavigationOptions: defaultNavOptions
});
```

and finally :

```
export default createAppContainer(AuditMomayezanNavigator);
```

In `MomayezanScreen` according params i loaded different data on flatlist. In page i want to set custom header so i do this:

```
MomayezanScreen.navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    const statusId = navigation.getParam('status');
    console.log(statusId);
    return {
        header: () => <CustomHeader
            title={`ممیزان ${statusId === 0 ? 'غیر فعال' : 'فعال'}`} />
    }
}
```

But unfortunately nothing is changed and header did not have any title.

[image]

Actually custom header is not set in header component! What is your idea?

I changed  `MomayezanScreen.navigationOptions` to this:

```
MomayezanScreen.navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    const statusId = navigation.getParam('status');
    console.log(statusId);
    return {
        headerTitle: `test`
    }
}
```

But still nothing is printed on header.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the header in `MomayezanScreen` which is inside `createMaterialTopTabNavigator`. You can only set the header in a screen which is inside `createStackNavigator`.

This is explained in detail in React Navigation docs: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-options-resolution.html

Comment: When i set header in stack navigator and i disable header in top tab navigator ,The header appear under tabs @satya164

Comment: I changed to this https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/NhFXTSCC4H/ and this is result http://pasteall.org/pic/show.php?id=14c01486f0b320fcf623f183f72c9e7c   as yuo can see header is under tabs @satya164